# ImportError: No module name 'tensorflow' when trying to run a GPU-enabled TensorFlow Image

Tags: nvidia, gpu, docker

I am trying to install tensorflow in my laptop with NVIDIA 1050 Ti GPU. I followed the steps in:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Under GPU Support, I used lspci | grep -i nvidia to verify that the GPU is available. Then, I did the following to verify nvidia-docker installation:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
```

Upon executation, a table shows up with NVIDIA-SMI 410.48 and Driver Version: 410.48 as the heading.

I did: `pip3 install tensorflow-gpu` already but when I executed (I replaced python with python3):

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module name 'tensorflow'
```

Could you please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you do all of the Linux post-install steps described on the webpage you referred to?  Looks like there are group and permissions issues that have to be solved.

Comment: I recall doing some post-install steps last night. To be sure, which ones on the webpage are you referring to?